# Thread persists after application termination due to AutoResetEvent signal in WaitOne state

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, waithandle, autoresetevent

I have an application that uses an AutoResetEvent (WaitOne/Set) in a queue for processing messages.  I'm noticing that when I terminate the a debug session from Visual Studio (Shift+F5) the original process for the application hangs around (but not always).  I manually re-attach the debugger to the process, and see it has single thread stuck on WaitHandle.WaitOne.

So my question is, what is the correct way to terminate threads that may be in a WaitOne state?

The first answer that sprang to mind was listen to the Application Exit event and doing a Set there, but I wasn't sure if this event was called reliably after these debug sessions, or if there is a more standard practice that I am not aware of.

And, as a second question, would you handle this differently for the application running in 'production' mode?

Comment: Hmm, you've got a nasty problem on your hands.  Terminating the debugging session is done with the biggest gun available in Windows, TerminateProcess().  Same kind of gun used in Taskmgr.exe.  There is only one possible way that this doesn't terminate the process, a kernel thread is busy and not completing an I/O request.  That's most certainly not an AutoResetEvent.  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Hans - so the WaitHandle I am seeing in the call stack once attaching the debugger is not the wait handle for the signal, but a different wait handle for a kernel i/o task?  The only i/o in this task is some logging, and that is really pretty straight forward (and only manually triggered every once in a while, not something happening with any frequency)

Comment: All I know is that what you describe doesn't make sense.  So without any documentation whatsoever I'll readily assume the description is wrong.  Post a stack trace with unmanaged debugging and Microsoft symbol servers enabled.

Comment: @Hans thanks for the suggestion, will do so when I get back to the office and have the code handy.  I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I just realized that I do in fact have another I/O operation.  My tired brain completely forgot about the TcpStream that is being read, and if I recall correctly when I glanced at the component I'm using it makes a blocking call to Read on the stream. Armed with this realization, and your the suggestions for more advanced debugging, I hope to resolve the problem on Mon

Comment: Of course, I haven't seen this behavior yet this week...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this (not a workaround)

First, you need to set an event that will fire when your application is going to die

```
// somewhere with global scope. On a singleton or in program class maybe
// this is set when you want to terminate your application
private static ManualResetEvent ExitWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

And this is how to use it elsewhere

```
// the event you want to check but it's blocking your application termination
private static AutoResetEvent yourEvent = new AutoResetEvent(true);

// the method where you have the problem
private static void FooAsync()
{
    try
    {
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[]{yourEvent, ExitWaitHandle});
        Checkpoint();

        // other stuff here

        // check if thread must die
        Checkpoint();
    }
    catch(ApplicationTerminatingException)
    {
        // thread must die, do cleanup and finalization stuff here
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        // holy cow! what should we do?
    }
}

private void CheckPoint()
{
    // fast check if the exit handle is set
    if(ExitWaitHandle.WaitOne(0))
    {
        throw new ApplicationTerminatingException(); // custom exception
    }
}
```

The only overhead is that after "some" code you need to set a checkpoint in order to abort your thread. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: this is a very interesting answer.  I'll be trying this first thing tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking at this again now that I have my code in front of me, and have a couple questions.  1) I presume your 'global' scope ExitWaitHandle should be public? and 2) Is the basic idea here that you open the 'gate' on the signal via the ExitWaitHandle during a shutdown process, thus releasing any wait handles and allow them to dispose themselves?

Comment: @Matt Yes, you open the "gate"! As for the event, it shouldn't be public, but accessible from all classes that need to listen to application terminate event. You can implement an observer pattern where subscribers are the threads. And just a little code-nazi comment: I prefer the `internal` keyword instead of `public` for such stuff.

Comment: Early testing seems to suggest this is working for me.  Thanks for the help on this long unresolved problem.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to set the thread as *background thread* using the [`Thread.IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property. When set on a thread that thread will not stop a process for exiting.

However, the thread may be interrupted at any time usually leading to undefined behavior depending on what your thread is doing. The best way to terminate a thread in my humble opinion is to signal the thread to exit, e.g. by setting a quit flag and set the `WaitHandle` and to wake it up then `Join`ing the thread.

Comment: The threading is actually being handled via a .NET 4 Task object.  I suppose I could do some manual threading...